# How to exclude the Parent log4j 2.11.2 from Spring boot version

Tags: maven, log4j, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to upgrade the log4j to 2.16.0 , log4j is getting upgraded to 2.16.0 .But I can
the log4j  2.11.2 version also in the build . I have tried to exclude the 2.11.2 but it is not happening .Could anyone suggest how to exclude the parent version of log4j 2.11.2 from the spring boot version .

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SampleService</name>
    <description> Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springboot.version>2.1.6.RELEASE</springboot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>logging-parent</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <uberJar>true</uberJar>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: [Log4J2 Vulnerability and Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2021/12/10/log4j2-vulnerability-and-spring-boot) Might Help

Comment: The first question is: Why do you use an old Spring Boot version?

Comment: @khmarbaise , Thank you for the quick response .My project is using the old Spring Boot version

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam , Thank you for the quick response .I have already referred the link  but the link has higher version of spring boot and when I tried with the higher version of spring boot I was facing compilation errors as I am using Mongodb 3.8.2 version . Since my project does not have time to testing I am trying to exclude the Parent version of log4j 2.11.2 and adding dependencies of 2.16.0 .But while building it is showing both versions.Could you suggest how to exclude the parent version of log4j in Sprint boot .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try using `<exclusions>` [as shown here.](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions)

I'd also recommend adding [an enforcer rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/bannedDependencies.html) to ban those CVE vulnerable log4j versions.